# Cube moving in a laggy way

Tags: unity, c#, movement

The movement on its own works perfectly fine, the problem is just that when I move diagonal, then the cube (the Player) is kinda lagging around and you can see its pixels moving to the edges of it. The whole map is kinda being rotated 20°. I would be very thankful for a little help on this!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BetterMovement: MonoBehaviour  {

   //Public Variables 
   public float moveSpeed;    
   public Rigidbody2D rb; 

   //Private Variables  
   private Vector2 moveDirection;  

   void Update() {
       ProcessedInputs(); 
   }

   void FixedUpdate() {    
       Move();
   }

   void ProcessedInputs() {
       float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
       moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY);
   }

   void Move() {
      rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed);
   }

}
```

Comment: This question would be better if it included a gif of the symptoms you're experiencing, and the code for the camera follow behaviour that turned out to be the real cause of the problem. Right now it's not very clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out on myself, it was basically because of the CameraFollow I was using. The speed of the camera was way to slow, so I guess it had to kinda do weird teleporting stuff. However I simply fixed it by changing the camerafollow speed to a higher number (In my situation 0.125 --> 1).